# How to fix why status bar space behind ScrollView in Xcode?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uiscrollview, uistoryboard

I added a scroll view to my view which is hover the status bar (I hid it). The scroll view is working fine, but when I'm scrolling to the top, I have a white space which disappears when I tap on my screen, and appears again when I scroll down then top.

I noticed that the scroll bar is not going to the top of my view, but stopped at the status bar.

Here are screenshots which show you what I mean.

Here I'm at the top of my view but the scroll bar isn't:

[image]

Here is the same view with the white status bar which appears when I scroll top again:

[image]

It disappear when I tap on my screen or scroll down.

Here are my constraints:

[image: constraints]

I think it's a problem of Layout Margin or something like that, but I don't what I should change?

I hide the status bar like that in my view controller:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.windowLevel = UIWindowLevelStatusBar

    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
}
```

**EDIT:** Even if I comment the line which hides the status bar, I still have the same problem with my scroll view. So the problem doesn't come from how I hide it.

Comment: Try changing the content insets to "Never" on the scroll view.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As [Sam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3585958/sam) said, I changed the `content insets` to "Never" on the scroll view and it works.

Answer (score 0):

While unrelated to your question, I have to react to the way you hide the status bar - the proper way is to override `prefersStatusBarHidden` in your view controller and call `self.setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()` in your `viewWillAppear`:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    self.setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
}

override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
    return true
}
```

**UPDATE**

Since your view controller is inside of a `UINavigationViewController`, you need to override `childViewControllerForStatusBarHidden` in `UINavigationViewController` to use `visibleViewController` as the controller to determine status bar hidden (I added override to `childViewControllerForStatusBarStyle` for the consistence):

```
extension UINavigationController {
    open override var childViewControllerForStatusBarStyle: UIViewController? {
        return visibleViewController
    }

    open override var childViewControllerForStatusBarHidden: UIViewController? {
        return visibleViewController
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes but this method doesn't work, I already tried it... But here is not the question

Comment: @cusmar it works, I just tried it.. if it does not work for you, it just means that you are not doing something properly.. is that `BorneVC` a rootViewController of the `keyWindow`? if not, how is it presented?

Comment: How do I check that? The BorneVC is a view controller connected to a Navigation Controller. This navigation controller is presented modally, over full screen, cover vertically. I don't know if it is the good thing to do, because when I add a new view controller after my BorneVC, and I connected a button from the BorneVC to it, my new view controller seems to be presented as a modal too (vertically), instead of a classic show transition. Do you know what can provide this error?

Comment: Where do I put the extension? In my BorneVC file?

Comment: @cusmar either create a new swift file, or after the class definition of the `BorneVC`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164496/discussion-between-cusmar-and-milan-nosa).